# java/xuggle - encode array of images into a movie

Tags: java, encode, movie, xuggle

how can I encode a array of images into a movie using xuggle and java?  I would like this to be at 30 fps.  I would be willing to use another framework than xuggle, but i believe xuggle would be easiest.  Probably a novice question, but thanks anywhay!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example for this [on Xuggle Wiki (Wayback Archive link, as it appears to be dead)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130320025028/http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Grow_Some_Balls) (obviously, replace calls to `Balls` with your array).