# Where do I find the Saved Image in Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, save, android-ffmpeg

Excuse me, quick question:

I have this routine of video stream, where I receive packets, convert them to byte[] ,then to bitmaps, then display them on the screen:

```
dsocket.receive(packetReceived); // receive packet
byte[] buff = packetReceived.getData(); // convert packet to byte[]
final Bitmap ReceivedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buff, 0, buff.length); // convert byte[] to bitmap image

runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // this is executed on the main (UI) thread
        imageView.setImageBitmap(ReceivedImage);
    }
});
```

Now, I want to implementing a Recording feature. Suggestions say I need to use FFmpeg (which I have no idea how) but first, I need to prepare a directory of the ordered images to then convert it to a video file. Do do that I will save all the images internally, and I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android) to save each image:

```
if(RecordVideo && !PauseRecording) {
    saveToInternalStorage(ReceivedImage, ImageNumber);
    ImageNumber++;
}
else
{
    if(!RecordVideo)
        ImageNumber = 0;
}

// ...

private void saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, int counter){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());

        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File MyDirectory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Create imageDir
        File MyPath = new File(MyDirectory,"Image" + counter + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(MyPath);

            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //return MyDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

But I can't seem to find the directory on my device (To actually see if I succeeded in creating the directory) Where is `// path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir` located exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDir` method of `ContextWrapper` will automatically create the `imageDir` directory if it does not already exist according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDir(java.lang.String,%20int)). Additionally, you cannot access anything in the `/data` directory outside of your application code unless you have root access. If you would like to view the images you saved in this directory, you can run the `adb` tool in a command prompt to move the images into a publicly accessible directory:

```
adb shell run-as com.your.packagename cp -r /data/data/com.your.packagename/app_data/imageDir /sdcard/imageDir
```

Note that the `run-as` command will only work if your application is debuggable.

You can replace `/sdcard/imageDir` with any directory you have permission to access on the device. If you would like to subsequently move the files off the device and onto your machine, you can use `adb pull` to pull the files from the public directory:

```
adb pull /sdcard/myDir C:\Users\Desktop
```

Again, replace `/sdcard/myDir` and `C:\Users\Desktop` with the appropriate source and destination directories.

Comment: Hi and thanks, sorry I am noob with these commands, how can I execute that within my code? It looks like a cmd thing no? Also, in c# desktop apps, we choose a directory `C:/ ... /Desktop` etc. I can't do that in Android?

Comment: You can use the above command to copy the private files to the sdcard and then pull the files to your machine using `adb pull` and specifying a directory. I'll update my answer to give an example.

Comment: Awesome, please and thanks in advance. I would want a path (or just imagine) something like `Internal storage\DCIM\100MEDIA\MyDirectoryOfImages`.  Maybe that is not how Android works.. I don't know still. Learning :)