# how to record a video with face filter like snapchat or instagram?

Tags: android, image-processing, video, video-recording

I didn't understand how to implement to record the video with face mask like instagram or snapchat 
I am using **relative layout** to preview and record the video after recording play the record video in **textureView** in the next activity 
i didn't understand which direction is choose to implement this scenarios.
I want this kind of output in the form of video[image]

If you can guide me and give me the proper direction and **helping link** of repository  to implement this feature i shall be very thanks to you.

Comment: besides that I do not even fully understand what your problem is, your question is too broad. please ask one distinct question and provide all necessary information.

Comment: basically i want to record video with face mask.

Comment: and face mask is an Android app or what?

Comment: no face mask is not an android app basically i implement the just like snapchat record the video with filter like dog etc.
but i didn't know how to implement this scenario

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315349/how-to-create-a-video-from-an-array-of-images-in-android

Comment: can you give me the sample code of project ?

Comment: i found a repository that help you a lot to implement this thing,Here is
https://github.com/ArslanKathia/Omoshiroi

Comment: i want to record video with face filter like snap chat or instagram can you please help me sugg for that any refrence or way

Comment: In above comment i mentioned the repository link but this link is breakdown. So i didn't have any other reference. If you found any link or repository please share with us.

Comment: @ArslanMaqbool Any update?