# I have a requirement to create a movie with audio by using images. how to?

Tags: android

I have a requirement to create a movie with audio by using images.
But I don't understand how to make that.

Please suggest any android library or something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315349/how-to-create-a-video-from-an-array-of-images-in-android see this link

Comment: chek this : https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a video from an array of images in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315349/how-to-create-a-video-from-an-array-of-images-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jcodec SequenceEncoder to convert sequence of images to MP4 file.

Refer http://jcodec.org/ for sample code & downloads

```
 compile 'org.jcodec:jcodec:0.2.2'
 compile 'org.jcodec:jcodec-android:0.2.2'
```

Now

Making a video with a set of images from memory:

```
SeekableByteChannel out = null;
try {
    out = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel("/tmp/output.mp4");
    // for Android use: AndroidSequenceEncoder
    AWTSequenceEncoder encoder = new AWTSequenceEncoder(out, Rational.R(25, 1));
    for (...) {
        // Generate the image, for Android use Bitmap
        BufferedImage image = ...;
        // Encode the image
        encoder.encodeImage(image);
    }
    // Finalize the encoding, i.e. clear the buffers, write the header, etc.
    encoder.finish();
} finally {
    NIOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro..i will check it

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create video from images with music is FFMPEG You can use ffmpeg to reate video using 
ffmpeg command

```
complexCommand= new String[]{"-i", "image%03d", "-framerate", " 15",  "-s", "720x1280", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-b", "800k","-preset","ultrafast", "/sdcard/video.mp4"};
```

here image%03d is your images with same name formate like image001, image002....
if you use image%02d  image name must be image01,image02.....

and to executee ffmpeg command in nadroid use ffmpeg by writingmind

```
  compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

image path sould be look like this `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image%03d.jpg`

let me know if any query