# How to make a video from a list of images?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application where users can select 3 gallery images. After click next button a video will be created with these 3 photos and user can save this video to sd card.

Comment: use ffmpeg library ..  you can create a video and add audio to that video ,you can  watermark that video as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using animation set in android that can help you achieve what you are after it is called FrameAnimation, here is an example on how to use it:

[FrameAnimation Example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/frame-animation/)

or checkout below code snippet if it helps :

```
` final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(6);
        dice.setImageResource(images[randomNum]);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
}, 500);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jcodec `SequenceEncoder` to convert sequence of images to MP4 file.

Sample code :

```
import org.jcodec.api.awt.SequenceEncoder;
...
SequenceEncoder enc = new SequenceEncoder(new File("filename"));
// GOP size will be supported in 0.2
// enc.getEncoder().setKeyInterval(25);
for(...) {
    BufferedImage image = ... // Obtain an image to encode
    enc.encodeImage(image);
}
enc.finish();
```

It's a java library so it's easy to import it into Android project, you don't have to use NDK unlike ffmpeg.

Refer http://jcodec.org/ for sample code & downloads.

According to [Abhishek V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868352/abhishek-v)

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315349/how-to-create-a-video-from-an-array-of-images-in-android/40374772#40374772) to see more