# Android (Kotlin): How to create a video from multiple images

Tags: android, kotlin, video-processing

I have an ArrayList of images and i want to make a video from them. Each Image should be one frame lasting about 0.5s or so.

What is the best way to create such video in Kotlin?

Comment: Look at this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315349/how-to-create-a-video-from-an-array-of-images-in-android